# How to Filter Object of arrays date key if selected key is consecutive

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object, reduce

I have a problem that's absolutely doing my head in. I have an Object of arrays where the key is a date:

```
{
2023-02-10: [{…}, {…}, {…}]
2023-02-13: [{…}, {…}]
2023-02-19: [{…}, {…}, {…}]
2023-02-27: [{…}, {…}, {…}]
2023-03-02: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2023-03-03: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2023-03-04: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2023-03-18: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
}
```

The user can select a date in the UI from the list above. What I'm trying to figure out is if a user selects **2023-02-10** and the next key is not a consecutive date ie **2023-02-13** then filter the object to only return the selected date.

If the user selects a date that **has** consecutive dates (selects **2023-03-02**) then filter the object to only return the selected date with consecutive dates (**2023-03-02, 2023-03-03, 2023-03-04**). Obviously including the contents of nested content.

I've been trying to combine methods using reduce and using date-fns to get the differenceInDays and output the correct result but I just can't for the life of me figure this out.

Would really appreciate any help or suggestions on this.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach increments the date we're filtering by only if the current date matches. Therefore, as soon as a date match fails, the date is not incremented and no more matches are possible.

```js
const data = {
  '2023-02-10': [{}, {}, {}],
  '2023-02-13': [{}, {}],
  '2023-02-19': [{}, {}, {}],
  '2023-02-27': [{}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-02': [{}, {}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-03': [{}, {}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-04': [{}, {}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-18': [{}, {}, {}, {}]
}

function nextDate(s) {
  let d = new Date(s)
  d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)
  return d.toISOString().substring(0,10)
}

function getConsecutive(data, i) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data)
    .filter(([d])=>d===i && (i=nextDate(d))))
}

console.log(getConsecutive(data, '2023-02-10'))
console.log(getConsecutive(data, '2023-03-02'))
console.log(getConsecutive(data, '2023-03-03'))
console.log(getConsecutive(data, '2023-03-04'))
console.log(getConsecutive(data, '2023-03-18'))
```

Comment: Dude, you nailed it, and in only two tiny functions no less haha. Thanks so much man, so so greatly appreciated. I feel like an absolute dunce that I couldn't work this out. :P Life saver.

Comment: btw Carsten is right, my code should read `d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate()+1);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
let obj = {
                "2023-02-10": [],
                "2023-02-13": [],
                "2023-02-19": [],
                "2023-02-27": [],
                "2023-03-02": [],
                "2023-03-03": [],
                "2023-03-04": [],
                "2023-03-18": []
                }

            let actDayStr = "2023-03-02";
            let actDay = new Date(actDayStr)/60/60/24/1000;
            let filteredObj = {};

            for (const key in obj) {
                if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
                    const element = obj[key];
                    let keyDay = new Date(key)/60/60/24/1000;

                    if(keyDay === actDay){
                        filteredObj[key] = element;
                    }
                    
                    if(keyDay > actDay){
                        let diffDay = keyDay - actDay;
                        if(diffDay === 1){
                            filteredObj[key] = element;
                            actDay = keyDay;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log('filteredObj :>> ', filteredObj);
```

Comment: Your code does not work unless the consecutive days are within the same month

Answer (score 1):

if you use date-fns you could do something like this, that is easy to understand :

```
import { addDays, format } from 'date-fns';
let data = {
  '2023-02-10': [{}, {}, {}],
  '2023-02-13': [{}, {}],
  '2023-02-19': [{}, {}, {}],
  '2023-02-27': [{}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-02': [{}, {}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-03': [{}, {}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-04': [{}, {}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-18': [{}, {}, {}, {}],
}

const selectedDate = '2023-03-03';
const previousDate = format(addDays(new Date(selectedDate), -1), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
const nextDate = format(addDays(new Date(selectedDate), 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

const filteredData = {};

// I did not understand if you wanted the date that the user is looking for to exist
// So if your user can look for a date that does not exist in data, you will need to move that 'if'
if (data[selectedDate]) {
    if (data[previousDate]) {
        filteredData[previousDate] = data[previousDate];
    }

    filteredData[selectedDate] = data[selectedDate];

    if (data[nextDate]) {
        filteredData[nextDate] = data[nextDate];
    }
}

//{
//  '2023-03-03': [ {}, {}, {}, {} ],
//  '2023-03-04': [ {}, {}, {}, {} ],
//  '2023-03-02': [ {}, {}, {}, {} ]
//}
console.log(filteredData);
```

Note that if you don't mind having undefined values you can use this if instead (edit: looking for a date of '2023-02-27')

```
if (data[selectedDate]) {
  filteredData[previousDate] = data[previousDate];
  filteredData[selectedDate] = data[selectedDate];
  filteredData[nextDate] = data[nextDate];
}

/*
  {
    '2023-02-26': undefined,
    '2023-02-27': [ {}, {}, {} ],
    '2023-02-28': undefined
  }
*/
console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Parks was almost there. But the methods `.getDate()` and `.setDate()` should be replaced by `.getUTCDate()` and `setUTCDate()` as otherwise the change to daylight saving times can cause problems. In 2023 this will happen from 25 to 26 March.

```js
const data = {
  '2023-02-10': [10, {}, {}],
  '2023-02-13': [13, {}],
  '2023-02-19': [19, {}, {}],
  '2023-02-28': [28, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-01': [1, {}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-02': [2, {}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-03': [3, {}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-25': [25, {}],
  '2023-03-26': [26, {}, {}, {}],
  '2023-03-27': [27, {}, {}, {}]
}

function nDate(s) {
  let d = new Date(s);
  d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate()+1);
  return d.toISOString().substring(0,10);
}
function consecutiveFrom(obj,s){
 let el,res=[];
 while(el=obj[s]) {
  res.push(el);
  s=nDate(s)
 }
 return res.flat();
}

console.log(consecutiveFrom(data,"2023-03-25"))
```

Using the UTC version of Date methods will make sure that the code will perform the same everywhere in the world, as otherwise day boundaries will be shifted during the transition phases.